# Devexpress free alternative

Tags: c#, web

I would like to develop web reports. What are the free alternatives?
**Requirement:**

1. Compatible with c#
2. drag n drop
3. free or low cost
4. website report

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: OS it should run on, what should it report (e.g. input data). Assume nobody ever heard of Devexpress and describe what you want to achieve – to improve your chances for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Syncfusion components

https://www.syncfusion.com

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion